# iOS - Fill Available Vertical Space

Tags: ios

I am new to iOS development, so excuse the ignorance.

I have 2 views, a `UIWebView` and another view containing controls for navigating the pages loaded in the webview (shown below).

The control bar is hidden at times, and I would like to have the `UIWebView` to dynamically fill the available space regardless if the control bar is shown or hidden.

How can I achieve this, and what is the preferred way (Auto-Layout, programmatically, etc)?

[image]

Comment: Are you creating the views in code or in a storyboard or xib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using autolayout in your storyboard.  You should have seven constraints on the web view and toolbar:

[image: constraints]

These constraints pin the top, left, and right edges of the web view to the root view; the left, bottom, and right edges of the toolbar to the root view; and the bottom edge of the web view to the top edge of the toolbar.

You need to connect an outlet in your view controller to the bottom constraint on the toolbar (the highlighted constraint in the screen shot):

[image: outlet to toolbar bottom constraint]

This constraint's constant is zero by default, which pins the bottom edge of the toolbar to the bottom of the root view.  To hide the toolbar, set the constraint's constant to the height of the toolbar.  You probably want to animate it:

```
- (void)hideToolbar {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        self.toolbarBottomConstraint.constant = self.toolbar.frame.size.height;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

To show the toolbar, set the constraint's constant back to zero:

```
- (void)showToolbar {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        self.toolbarBottomConstraint.constant = 0;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in a few ways; the best way is going to mesh with whatever your previous coding practices are in the project.

You could change the frame in layoutSubviews:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
  CGRect frame = self.webView.frame;
  frame.size.height = self.bottomBar.frame.origin.y;
  self.webView.frame = frame;
}
```

You could add constraints:

```
- (void)loadView {
  [self.webView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[_webView]-[_bottomBar]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_webView, _bottomBar)]];
}
```

You could add constraints in Storyboard as well, but I don't know how to make a gif demonstrating this. You should also only consider this if you're already using a Storyboard.

If you're animating the position of the bottom bar, you will probably want to keep the frame size of your webView in sync. Using NSLayoutConstraints will have this happen automagically; or you could update the web view frame in the same animation block.

Another thing to investigate would be keeping the frame of the web view the same, matching the maximum height that it will appear at. When you show and hide the bottom bar, adjust `webView.scrollView.contentInset` to change the bottom content padding.